# Need to replace string with variable in specific Pandas dataframe slice

Tags: python, pandas, syntax

I have a Pandas dataframe where some rows have NaN in some columns. I have a specific column wherein I need to replace the NaN with a given integer.

My starting df:

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3
0  10       20       30
1  11       NaN      NaN
2  12       NaN      NaN
```

My goal df:

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3
0  10       20       30
1  11       5        NaN
2  12       5        NaN
```

I'm trying to remove anything hardcoded in the script. (Someone else with much more experience than I wrote the initial code and I need to update it).
I've set the variables:

```
column_name = 'Column2'
new_integer = 5
```

So far I have:

```
df.loc[df.Column2.isna(), column_name] = new_integer
```

I can't figure out how to replace the remaining Column2 string with the variable column_name.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Column1': [10, 11, 12], 
     'Column2': [20, np.nan, np.nan], 
     'Column3': [30, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
column_name = 'Column2'
new_integer = 5

df[column_name] = df[column_name].fillna(new_integer)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
I'm very new to this - do you know if there's a reason to use the code in the manner originally written with .isna as opposed to using the .fillna as you suggest? Your way seems much simpler and seems to give me the behavior I need, but I'm very new to python and pandas so I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: I cannot think of any advantage of using isna() over fillna().